# FB login Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

After implementing the following , OnCancel method is being called :

```
<activity
            android:name=".FbLoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fb_login"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider456579934439214"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />


        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

In the Activity:

```
public class FbLoginActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvTermsLink;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    String TAG="FbLoginActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_login);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_work_history", "user_relationships", "user_relationship_details",
                "user_education_history"));


        tvTermsLink=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fbl_tv_termsLink);
        tvTermsLink.setText(Html.fromHtml("By logging in you accept the <a href=\"http://crownit.in/terms\">Terms & Conditions</a> "));

        tvTermsLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());




        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            });


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

After prolonged referring the online resources, I am not able to understand whats wrong in the code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you want to call?

Comment: I want to call onSuccess...

Comment: did u generated debug key properly?

Comment: did u added app details to developers console?

Comment: are u logging in using different login id other then developer id?

Comment: This may be a valid bug. You should provide more information on how to reproduce this issue and create a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs, including info like what SDK version you're using any any logcat that might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using facebook's default login button than no need to set onclick event. you can use it like this.

```html
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
    try {
     id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     String name = object.getString("name");
     String email = object.getString("email");
     String gender = object.getString("gender");
     String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

if you using customized facebook button than just check my answer here [facebook login with customized button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928)