# Facebook 4.x Login SDK Not Completing Login Process

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/login-with-facebook-android-studio-using-facebook-sdk-4/) and it was working, but now when I click on the login button, I get a progress spinner that appears for a brief moment, then disappears. I have tried to debug, and I'm not even hitting this callback:

```
 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView displayName;

    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };



    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken1) {

            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                displayMessage(newProfile);
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayName);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            displayName.setText(profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
    }


}
```

Comment: When you say it was working, you changed something afterwards or not ?

Comment: look at my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239250/fb-login-android/31354083#31354083

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issues was caused by not having my `uses-permission` in the right place. I don't know why this would allow the app to work once or twice, but it did. I had to make my manifest look like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        ....
```

Before, it looked like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app" >


    <application
        ....
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```